# Cannot Start Ubuntu in Chromebook without Web Browsing First

Tags: 14.04, xorg, chromebook, chromeos

I just got a Toshiba 13.3-inch Chromebook 2 and have set up Ubuntu Trusty Tahr with Unity through crouton.

Whenever I turn the computer back on after having put it to sleep or shut it down, I cannot load Ubuntu without first web browsing a little. Specifically, I can log in as `chronos` from the chromebook's log-in screen, but when I try to run `sudo startunity` the computer sends back the following error after performing most of the actions it would normally take to load Ubuntu normally:

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
```

It says a couple of other things after that like it tells me to consult the X.Org Foundation's Support at [wiki.xorg](http://wiki.x.org) and check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", but I haven't found anything of use on the wiki and that log file doesn't appear to exist.

Then it says

`/usr/bin/xinit: giving up`

`/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: connection refused`

`/usr/bin/xinit: server error`

before unmounting the process.

The same thing happens when I try to get to Ubuntu as a guest; however, I can overcome this issue by either logging in as a registered user on the chromebook or by typing any url into the url bar of the web browser as a guest.

Does anyone know why this happens or how to work around the issue so that I can boot into Ubuntu as the first thing I do after the computer turns on? I've seen other questions about booting directly into Ubuntu instead of ChromeOS on start-up, but that's not what I'm looking for here.